# Looking to fill missing time periods with zero for each ID (Athena SQL)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

In my data, I'm looking at quarterly counts per user. For all of the quarters that are missing, I'd like to impute them with 0. Here is an example:

Here is my current dataset:

```
ID Qtr    Count
1  2018Q1 1
1  2018Q3 1
1  2018Q4 2
2  2018Q1 4
2  2018Q2 6
2  2019Q3 2
2  2019Q4 1
3  2018Q1 8
3  2018Q2 5
3  2018Q3 2
3  2018Q4 4
3  2019Q1 5
```

Updated table:

```
ID Qtr    Count
1  2018Q1 1
1  2018Q2 0
1  2018Q3 1
1  2018Q4 2
1  2019Q1 0
1  2019Q2 0
1  2019Q3 0
1  2019Q4 0
2  2018Q1 4
2  2018Q2 6
2  2018Q3 0
2  2018Q4 0
2  2019Q1 0
2  2019Q2 0
2  2019Q3 2
2  2019Q4 1
3  2018Q1 8
3  2018Q2 5
3  2018Q3 2
3  2018Q4 4
3  2019Q1 5
3  2019Q2 0
3  2019Q3 0
3  2019Q4 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, to solve this we will first all the *year+quarter* values for a particular ID and then we can calculate the  count for each *year+quarter*. So the solution is divided into two steps as follows:

1. Create a dataset to get all the year+quarter values per ID.
2. CROSS JOIN it with original data to get all the result.

#### 1. CREATE A DATASET:

To create dataset the steps will be:

1. Get unique ID,year combination
2. Convert it year data to year+quarter data.
3. Seperate out it array entry.

**Get unique ID,year combination:**

```
SELECT ID, ARRAY[substr(Qtr, 1, 4)] AS year from table_name 
GROUP BY ID, ARRAY[substr(Qtr, 1, 4)]
```

**Convert it year data to year+quarter data:**

```
WITH dataset AS (
SELECT ID, ARRAY[substr(Qtr, 1, 4)] AS year from table_name 
GROUP BY ID, ARRAY[substr(Qtr, 1, 4)]
)
select ID, transform(year, x->x||'Q1') || transform(year, x->x||'Q2') || transform(year, x->x||'Q3') ||
transform(year, x->x||'Q4') 
AS year from dataset
```

**Seperate out it array entry:**

```
WITH dataset AS (
    WITH inner_dataset AS (
      SELECT ID, ARRAY[substr(Qtr, 1, 4)] AS year from table_name 
      GROUP BY ID, ARRAY[substr(Qtr, 1, 4)]
     )
     select ID, transform(year, x->x||'Q1') || transform(year, x->x||'Q2') || 
     transform(year, x->x||'Q3') || transform(year, x->x||'Q4') 
     AS year from inner_dataset
)
SELECT ID,yr from dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(year) AS t(yr)
```

Output of this query will be the ROWS of **ID,year+quarter** having all the quarters for each id. Now the next step will be to convert it into final dataset and then JOIN this data with original table.

#### 2. CROSS JOIN it with original data to get all the result.

```
SELECT table_name.ID,final_dataset.yr,coalesce(table_name.Count,0)
FROM table_name
CROSS JOIN final_dataset
ON table_name.ID = final_dataset.ID AND table_name.Qtr = final_dataset.yr
ORDER BY table_name.ID,final_dataset.yr
```

*coalesce()* is used to convert NULL values to 0.

### FINAL QUERY:

```
WITH final_dataset AS (
  WITH dataset AS (
      WITH inner_dataset AS (
        SELECT ID, ARRAY[substr(Qtr, 1, 4)] AS year from table_name 
        GROUP BY ID, ARRAY[substr(Qtr, 1, 4)]
       )
       select ID, transform(year, x->x||'Q1') || transform(year, x->x||'Q2') || 
       transform(year, x->x||'Q3') || transform(year, x->x||'Q4') 
       AS year from inner_dataset
  )
  SELECT ID,yr from dataset
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(year) AS t(yr)
)
SELECT table_name.ID,final_dataset.yr,coalesce(table_name.Count,0)
FROM table_name
CROSS JOIN final_dataset
ON table_name.ID = final_dataset.ID AND table_name.Qtr = final_dataset.yr
ORDER BY table_name.ID,final_dataset.yr
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to produce a table with zeroes.
For this [`sequence()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) and [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) come particularily useful.

Here is an example where your data has only quarter and count (no `id`).

```
presto:default> SELECT coalesce(t.q, a.q), coalesce(t.c, 0)
             -> FROM (VALUES ('2018Q1', 1)) t(q, c)
             -> RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
             ->     SELECT CAST(y AS varchar) || 'Q' || CAST(x AS varchar) AS q
             ->     FROM UNNEST(sequence(2018, 2019)) _(y)
             ->     CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequence(1, 4)) _(x)
             -> ) a ON t.q = a.q
             -> ;
 _col0  | _col1
--------+-------
 2018Q1 |     1
 2018Q3 |     0
 2019Q1 |     0
 2018Q4 |     0
 2019Q3 |     0
 2019Q2 |     0
 2018Q2 |     0
 2019Q4 |     0
(8 rows)
```

(Tested on Presto 322)

You can generalize it easily for `id`:

```
presto:default> WITH source_table AS (
             ->     SELECT *
             ->     FROM (VALUES (1, '2018Q1', 13), (2, '2018Q2', 42)) t(id, q, c)
             -> )
             -> SELECT id, q, coalesce(c, 0)
             -> FROM source_table
             -> RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
             ->     SELECT id, CAST(y AS varchar) || 'Q' || CAST(x AS varchar) AS q
             ->     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM source_table)
             ->     CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequence(2018, 2019)) _(y)
             ->     CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequence(1, 4)) _(x)
             -> ) a USING(id, q)
             -> ;
 id |   q    | _col2
----+--------+-------
  1 | 2018Q1 |    13
  2 | 2018Q2 |    42
  2 | 2019Q3 |     0
  1 | 2018Q2 |     0
  1 | 2019Q3 |     0
  2 | 2018Q4 |     0
  1 | 2019Q2 |     0
  1 | 2019Q4 |     0
  2 | 2019Q4 |     0
  2 | 2018Q3 |     0
  2 | 2019Q2 |     0
  1 | 2018Q3 |     0
  1 | 2019Q1 |     0
  2 | 2019Q1 |     0
  2 | 2018Q1 |     0
  1 | 2018Q4 |     0
(16 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create table containing all your quarters (in example `quarters_`) and then join data (in example some_data) to it.

```
create table some_data (year number, quarter number, data varchar2(10));
insert into some_data values(2018,3,'AAAA');

create table  quarters_ (signature varchar2(20), year number, quarter_number number);
insert into quarters_ (signature, year, quarter_number) values ('2018Q1', 2018, 1);
insert into quarters_ (signature, year, quarter_number) values ('2018Q2', 2018, 2);
insert into quarters_ (signature, year, quarter_number) values ('2018Q3', 2018, 3);
insert into quarters_ (signature, year, quarter_number) values ('2018Q4', 2018, 4);
insert into quarters_ (signature, year, quarter_number) values ('2019Q1', 2019, 1);
insert into quarters_ (signature, year, quarter_number) values ('2019Q2', 2019, 2);
insert into quarters_ (signature, year, quarter_number) values ('2019Q3', 2019, 3);
insert into quarters_ (signature, year, quarter_number) values ('2019Q4', 2019, 4);

select signature as Qtr, count (s.data) as count
from quarters_ q
left join some_data s on s.quarter = q.quarter_number and s.year = q.year
group by q.signature
```